# Sql server T SQL 2014 (Reusing same query)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a query which joins 3,4 tables(like select * from table1 join table2 join table3) and the same query is used in my stored procedure multiple time. Is there any way to keep that query in one place and i can use it in my entire stored procedure(with in a single stored procedure)?

```
SELECT p.PK_PatientID
        FROM Patients p
        INNER JOIN PT ON e.FK_PatientID = p.PK_PatientID
        INNER JOIN PN n ON n.FK_PatientEncounterID = e.PK_PatientEncounterID
        INNER JOIN BP ep ON ep.FK_PatientEncounterID = e.PK_PatientEncounterID
        INNER JOIN SOP pd ON ep.FK_SharedProcedureDetailID = pd.PK_SharedOfficeProcedureDetailID
        INNER JOIN CQM vs ON pd.FK_SharedProcedureCode = vs.Code
```

This is the query i want to use it in my procedure multiple time

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: Check my question again. i edited. i wanted to use the same query multiple time in procedure, if there is anything like CTE which is used in entire SP (Whereas in CTE, it will be available only in next line not entire procedure)

Comment: Are you using the results of that query in a join? If so, you can start your procedure off by inserting the results into a temp table.

Comment: i knew i can use temp table. but i dont want temptable, tablevariable, is there anything new available in sql 2014 to meet my requirement

Comment: Why do you not want to use a temp table or temp variable?

Answer (score 1):

You could use Temp table or Table variable and insert data into it,if you are using the query multiple times

If you don't want to use temp tables or tables variables for reasons unknown,you could use a view

Answer (score 1):

You can store your select query in a view:

```
CREATE VIEW vW_Example
AS
    SELECT p.PK_PatientID
        FROM Patients p
        INNER JOIN PT ON e.FK_PatientID = p.PK_PatientID
        INNER JOIN PN n ON n.FK_PatientEncounterID = e.PK_PatientEncounterID
        INNER JOIN BP ep ON ep.FK_PatientEncounterID = e.PK_PatientEncounterID
        INNER JOIN SOP pd ON ep.FK_SharedProcedureDetailID = pd.PK_SharedOfficeProcedureDetailID
        INNER JOIN CQM vs ON pd.FK_SharedProcedureCode = vs.Code
```

Then you can call the view like this:

```
SELECT * FROM vW_Example
```